# Need some help on an SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to grab a user_id from my users tables that has the most referrals. Sorry for the vague title, I'm not sure what this is called.

Using PHP and MYSQL.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(180) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(180) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `registered` varchar(180) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `lastonline` varchar(180) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `referral` varchar(180) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(180) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `points` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6544 ;
```

A user will look like this,

```
1, 'username', 'ipaddy', 'date', 'date', '**REFERRAL**', 'url', 13633
```

I'm trying to find the user_id that has the most of the same referral in all of the users tables. Lets say user 4 has 10 different users with the same thing in the referral varchar. How can i select see user 4 without going through every single user, logging their referrals, and then pick the one with the most.

There has to be an easier way...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, referral is the `name` of another user, not the `user_id`.

Comment: so, referral here is the user_id of another user?

Comment: no sorry, referral is a varchar of `name` of another user. I wasn't thinking when i made the original table (it was late) i should of went by user_id's. In fact, i should of made an entire new table just for referrals and LEFT JOIN it to the users table... But now i'm stuck right now because the site is live and there are already 10K users with this setup.

Comment: but, this might cause you a problem on future development. for name here is not a unique entity. furthermore, if you have edit profile on your system, editing the name will cause you to lose your reference in this scenario.

Comment: Users can not change their names, they are locked in on signup. Normally i would make a new table for something like this, i was hacking away to get the project finished. Now its biting me in the butt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little extra added to your SQL:

```
SELECT referral, count(*) AS count FROM users 
WHERE referral IS NOT NULL AND referral != ''
GROUP BY referral ORDER BY COUNT(referral) DESC
```

Comment: The top query returns 1 for all the referrals and the bottom query returns user_id 1 count 1.

Comment: In this case can you give me a table dump or something like that? Or more rows? It works for me on my similar table.

Comment: So here every user has only one referral therefore you cant get the user_id with the most referrals because there will be always '1'. So then I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to get which referral exists at the most? Other case you need to create a UserAndReferral table to hold the user <-> referral relations.

Comment: Yes i wish to get what referral shows up the most. When i do a site upgrade i'll fix this and write some scripts to move everything over to the new setup.. But for now i need a way to grab what exists the most

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12090/discussion-between-e3po-and-papaiatis)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, this will work for you. But try to consider my advise above. However for now, use this one.

```
SELECT 
    ref.prime,
    ref.num_of_refferals
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        referral AS prime,
        COUNT(*) AS num_of_refferals,
        NAME
    FROM
        users
        WHERE
                referral != ''
    GROUP BY
        referral
) AS ref
ORDER BY 
    ref.num_of_refferals
DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Prime becomes blank and [num_of_refferals: 1595].

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though because other users didn't have referrals, it was counting them as well and returning a blank for the top referral.

Papaiatis provided the following

```
SELECT referral FROM users GROUP BY referral ORDER BY COUNT(referral) DESC LIMIT 1
```

and I made sure that the referral field was not empty and i wanted to grab the count of referrals the user had.

```
SELECT referral, count(*) as count FROM users WHERE referral != '' GROUP BY referral ORDER BY COUNT(referral) DESC
```

Thanks for the help!